# How to upload file from pc to another server with Curl & Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, file-upload

I'm building a file upload site and I have 2 servers - 1 for display the site , and 1 for store the files.

The main site build on Laravel and the other server is just PHP.

I want to send the file from the main site and handle him on the other server and after uploadind to get the info and store it on one DB - of the main site.

If there is diffrenet and better way then Curl I'll be happy to hear.
Sorry about my english and thanks to the helpers :)

EDIT -

The answer of Afik is currect but I need something else.
When I upload the file I need to convert it with FFMPEG and I cant do that with ftp, there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a filesystem in your Laravel app inside config/filesystem.php

something like that:

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver'   => 'ftp',
    'host'     => 'ftp.example.com',
    'username' => 'your-username',
    'password' => 'your-password',
 ]
```

you can use FTP, SSH whatever you want.

after you have set it up change the default storage to this one on the same file:

```
'default' => 'ftp',
```

than to push files to the server use the following command:

```
Storage::put('file.jpg');
```

If you want to keep using the local default filesystem you can than specify the driver every time you wish to use it:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('file.jpg');
```

You can also use the same way with the  function "get" to get the file from the other end.

You can check it out on the Laravel documentation for more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, but how can i test it on localhost and can i upload file from pc to the second server or I need to upload it to my server and then to move it to the ftp?

Comment: Just test it, work perfect Thank you, I have last question, do you know if there is a way to make progress bar to this transfer?

Comment: Once it's up on your server you don't need to care what the user get on his side. but if you want a progress bar while it's uploading on the user's browser until you get it to your server you can use jQuery or bootstrap plugins for it, like this one: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Thank you, already solve it yesterday. :)